How to resolve "InvalidOperationException: A second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed."
I'm encountering an issue with my ASP.NET Core application where I'm receiving the following exception:
InvalidOperationException: A second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads concurrently using the same instance of DbContext.

This exception occurs within my ASP.NET Core application when handling requests in a controller action method. The stack trace indicates that it passes through MediatR pipeline behaviors before reaching the core domain logic.
The error occurs consistently on every 3rd or 4th request, and each request is identical.
Here are the key points of my setup:
I'm using ASP.NET Core with MediatR for handling requests.
Entity Framework Core is used for data access, with DbContext instances registered with scoped lifetime in dependency injection.
The exception occurs intermittently on the server environment but not in my local development environment.
I've reviewed my code and ensured that DbContext instances are being used within their scoped lifetimes and are not accessed concurrently from multiple threads within the same scope.
I'm seeking guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue. Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated!
Verified that asynchronous operations involving DbContext are awaited properly and that no other operations are started on the same DbContext instance before the asynchronous operation completes.
